# GNU make variable and shell variable in recipe

Tags: shell, variables, makefile, gnu, recipe

I'm little confused the make variable and shell variable in recipe.
as the each line of recipe is interpret as the shell, can i do the shell variable assignment?
following is the example:

```
.ONESHELL:
all:
    param="hello"
    echo $(param)
```

//--------------------
no output...
and i know we can use eval to the variable assignment, but it looks as make variable.
how can i just perform the normal shell variable assignment which i want to hold the shell command return value.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(param)` is expanded by GNU make. To make it expanded by the shell do `$${param}`. [Using Variables in Recipes](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Variables-in-Recipes):

> Variable and function references in recipes have identical syntax and semantics to references elsewhere in the makefile. They also have the same quoting rules: if you want a dollar sign to appear in your recipe, you must double it (‘$$’). For shells like the default shell, that use dollar signs to introduce variables, **it’s important to keep clear in your mind whether the variable you want to reference is a make variable (use a single dollar sign) or a shell variable (use two dollar signs)**.

Comment: thank, it works. and BTW, in this case, the .ONESHELL: doesn't work.    all:
 @param="hello"; \
 echo $${param}     it can print out "hello", if use .ONESHELL nothing output.

Comment: @尹慧贤 `.ONESHELL` works as expected for me with your sample code and `$$`.

Comment: Thanks again,will try it.

Comment: update make from 3.8.1 to 4.1, then .ONESHELL works.